# can we upload/publish a customer app to appstore by using developer university program?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I am planning to create an app to publish on Appstore, I came to know about university developer program, which allows a team of people to share code and test application. My concern is whether I will be able to upload app to store using this program.

Answer (score -1):

University developer program only can deploy ur device whitch is connected to the transmission line.

https://www.quora.com/Who-is-in-the-Apple-iOS-Developer-University-Program

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Aside from this being a link-only answer: the question itself is off-topic here (it's about app store policies).

Comment: It's related to account permissions, what can u answer more about this?